# How can this object be an object but not an object?

Tags: php, serialization

This

```
if(is_object($value)) echo 'AAA';
if(gettype($value)==='object') echo 'BBB'
```

Prints 'BBB'.

Specifically, value is `__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object` which is the result of  `unserialize`. Why would `is_object` return false though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PHP manual:](https://www.php.net/is_object)

> Note:
>
> This function will return FALSE if
> used on an unserialized object where
> the class definition is not present
> (even though gettype() returns
> object).

Comment: Well that's just silly... so what, now I'm supposed to do `gettype($value)==='object'` even though those same docs specifically recommend against it?

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, be sure that the class definition for your object is present before you unserialize.

Answer (score 2):

As AJ was explaining, the object isn't an object because it's incomplete.  An object was put into _SESSION then later tried failed to be de-serialized and woken up because the objects class hasn't been defined yet.  If you can resolve this by either including the class into scope before starting session's or by using __autoload or spl_autoload_register as a last ditch rescue attempt.

Comment: It's a serialization of a JavaScript object. Legacy code, I can't really change the structure of the serialization. Also, it doesn't really need to be an object at all... it *should* deserialize to an associative array. `json_encode/decode` didn't exist when this code was written :\

Comment: JavaScript?  JSON?  Perhaps update your original question with the pertinent info then, as it stands it appears to be purely a PHP question.

Comment: @AJ I'm as confused as you are now.

Comment: @AJ/David: What's so confusing? It is a purely PHP question. I'm just saying that the serialized object is created via JavaScript. Specifically, it creates a string which PHP's `unserialize` can understand. When the form is posted, it's passed to PHP. I can't change the JS portion, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark How exactly are you doing that?  Are you building a PHP serialized object string in Javascript and passing it to PHP?

Comment: @David: Yes... that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mark Pretty cool, just make sure to validate the serialization string is the class you want and not something expected.  Most security docs and commentary I've read, a point of exploitation is to inject an undesired class object in tandem with some other XSS exploit to wreak havoc.

Comment: @David: Well, like I was saying, the object is really just used as an associative array; it doesn't need to be a specific type. We just iterate over it. I suppose a clever attack would be for them to inject some other class with an overwritten iterator method, so that when it get called....evil stuff happens. Sneaky. Thanks for the heads up.